# Add a custom UI Object (UISwitch) to an iOS project

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, custom-controls

I'm trying to add a custom `UISwitch` to my app using [DCRoundSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch), however I'm struggling to figure out how to implement it correctly. After adding the files to my project I went to change my UISwitch to a DCRoundSwitch but have run into several problems, including the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.

I've tried (1) going to the Xib, selecting the Switch, opening the identity selector and changing the custom class, but the only option I see is `UISwitch`. (2) I've also tried changing the `UISwitch` to `DCRoundSwitch` in the code, but that results in the error mentioned above when I run it.

I feel like I'm missing a step, but I'm not sure what. Do I need to delete the switch and re-add the new switch? I've never done this programmatically before.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why? I edited the question to be a little more clear, but it's essentially still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution!

The way to add a custom UI object in IB (after adding the code to your project) is to *drag a generic UIView object onto your Xib*, *resize it as needed*, then *switch to the identity inspector and change the class from UIView to DCRoundSwitch* (or other custom object).

**Caveat:** If you don't see your custom object listed, try building your project or closing and re-opening xCode. xCode 4 and up should recognize it after you've added your code to compiled sources.

Comment: Adding custom controls this way works great. It works because under the covers the runtime will call the custom control's `initWithCoder` method. Any idea how in XCode's inspector to assign some value that can be retrieved during `initWithCoder`?

Answer (score 0):

`DCRoundSwitch` is not `UISwitch` Custom Class. this is a inherited from `UIControl`. this mean is in interface builder you not set `UISwitch` CustomClass. `UISwitch` between `DCRoundSwitch` is not related at all. so you must set Programmatically.

Comment: I haven't added UI objects programmatically before. Do you have any suggestions? A simple sample would be awesome.

Comment: Alloc/init with a frame (or other options) - add to your view as a subview - use the frame/center property to position - enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? https://github.com/robertchin/rcswitch (I used that sample for my apps)

Comment: Yes I found a couple projects/subclasses I could use, my issue is not finding and adding the code to my project, it's actually adding the new switch programmatically or through IB. I'm new to xCode and must be missing a step.

Comment: @Kyle I see. Do you mind to send me a sample project so that I can see the issue?